# Are there two curves that can be mapped between with a 2-isogeny that support pairing checks and Montgomery ladders?

Tags: pairings

Are there two curves that can be mapped between using a 2-isogeny that support pairing checks on on curve and Montgomery ladders on another?

Is there a paper?